# Extract some character from file MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab

txt file content :  2;123687452321215454
I would like to get the fist character "2"

I tried :

```
s = fileread(filepath);
[token, remain] = strtok(s)
token =
this returns :
token =

2;123687452321215454
remain =
```

how could I get only the first "2" ?

Comment: The point of using `strtok` is to break a string into several components using a `delimiter`. Without a delimiter, `strtok(s)` read the entire line while `strtok(s,';')` uses `;` to break it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get whatever is before the `;`, use:

```
[token, remain] = strtok(s,';')
```

This will give you more than one character if that's what there is before the `;`. If you just want the first character, use `token(1)`. If you want the last character before the `;` use `token(end)`.

Comment: strtok(s,';') will gives charcaters after ";" whereas I would like to get the first character debore ";"

Comment: it's ok , just to understand why token(end) chereas I'm looking for the first charcater ?

Comment: You said "first character _before_ `;`": that's the ending character of the token. For example: with `s = '123;45'` the token is `123`. So token(1) is `1`, `token(end)` is `3`.